# Inserting custom css into iframe (Wordpress - Usual solutions not working)

Tags: wordpress, iframe

so I'm aware there are already similar questions on here, the reason I ask this question is because I cannot get any of the other solutions to work.

So what I've do is I have an iframe in my html like so:

```
<iframe name="frame1" id="frame1" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)" style="width:100%; height:1000px;" src="https://www.treeofgnosis.com/community/discussion/151/faq"></iframe>
```

and then I have added the code to add custom CSS to the iframe like so directly below in the html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
var $head = $('#frame1 head');
var url = "/wp-content/themes/layerswp/iframe.css";
$head.append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + url + '" />');              
});
alert("Alert\$head function us running");
</script>
```

From what I can tell, the code is all running (the iframe shows and so does the alert) - but the custom  is not appending into the iframe's content's head when I check the DOM.

When I manually insert the  into the head after the page has loaded, the css does apply, so the error isn't there.

Here is a link to the page I'm working on, the iframe is right at the bottom of the screen: https://www.treeofgnosis.com/faq/

Any help would be appreciated, I have no idea why things aren't working. I have also tried some other code variations - but the situation remains pretty much the same. So really, I am really looking for WHY things aren't working.

(PS in the console log, there are no errors related to this)

Comment: Simple approach can be that have #id for iframe , then apply all that css to that iframe#id from the main css without needing any appending to the iframe...You see any issues wit this approach?

Comment: Well Im trying to add CSS to the head WITHIN the iframe. I'm not trying to add css for the iframe itself. That is, I'm trying to change the content isnide the iframe. So i think your solution won't work for that